# NetTrain ClassifierFunction/NetChain Entropy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Obtain a trained network from NetTrain as

```
net = NetTrain[net, dat];
```

which i believe returns a ClassifierFunction (although Head[net] returns NetChain).

In the example docs for NetTrain it says:

> From a random sample, select the images for which the net produces
>   highest and lowest entropy predictions. High entropy inputs can be
>   interpreted as those for which the net is most uncertain about the
>   correct class:

```
images = RandomSample[Keys[dat], 5000];
entropies = net[images, "Entropy"];
```

**My question is: what is "Entropy" here and how is it calculated?**  Is the entropy returned similar to entropy from ImageMeasurments or is it actually based on some information produced by the network etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the source code:

> C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.0\SystemFiles\Components\NeuralNetworks\Decoders\Class.m

```
DEntropy = Compile[{{probs, _Real, 1}}, Module[{e = 0.},
    Do[
        If[2*$MachineEpsilon <= p <= 1., e -= p * Log[p]],
        {p, probs}
    ];
    e
], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```